# Streaming multiple music with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer

I have an app that I want to make which requires streaming audio files from web server. I use `AVPlayer` as the player. The problem is, some responses that I am receiving from the server has two audio files on it. And this makes the streaming hard. My audio player UI by the way is like this:

[image]

I have a slider for the streamed time ranges (the black one) and another slider for the `AVPlayer.currentTime`. I have two audio music streamed and their music durations are added together which is now 8:46. My first music has 6 minutes duration and my second music has 1:46. As you can see in the above photo, my streamed time ranges slider indicates that `AVAsset` has completely streamed the first music. My problem is, I can't continue streaming and playing the next music when the first one has reached it's end. It just stop and the slider value gets back to 0.

What I want to accomplish is that when the first item has reached its end, `AVPlayer` would load another player item and that would be the second music. Will continue to play and slider will continue to move.

Is this possible? What are your suggestions? Thanks experts.

Answer (score 0):

To load audio files one after the other, you can use AVQueuePlayer.

```
 NSURL *song1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"audio url1"]; 
 NSURL *song2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"audio url2"];

 AVPlayerItem *playerItem1 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:song1];
 AVPlayerItem *playerItem2 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:song2];

 NSArray *songs = @[playerItem1, playerItem2];

 self.queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:songs];
 [self.queuePlayer play];
```

Hope this might help you.